# Is the phrase "by way of notice" an acceptable use of the idiom/expression "by way of"?

Tags: idioms, expressions, american-english

Oftentimes when I write emails to notifying co-workers of any planned absences I will say something along the lines of:

> By way of advanced notice, I will be out of the office on Tuesday, April 1st.

Is this proper English? Is there a better way to say this?

If this is improper, is there ever a valid sentence in which you could say "by way of notice"?

Comment: *advanced* should be *advance*—"advanced notice" would be notice which was expected later but has been "advanced" to an earlier occasion. But like Chris, below, I think the entire phrase is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

You're stating the obvious about the notice. You can remove that notice sentence and provide something more useful like contact details for any urgent work etc.